# Listening for JOptionPane events when embedded?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane

`JOptionPane` can be used as an "embedded" component, like here:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
log.debug("Options are: ", pane.getOptions());
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(800, 800);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

How is it possible to attach listener to option pane buttons, to react when user clicks some button?

Comment: From the Java doc: _"JOptionPane makes it easy to pop up a standard dialog box that prompts users for a value or informs them of something"_ . JOptionPane are not meant to be embedded in a standard JFrame. Btw, `frame.pack();
frame.setSize(800, 800);` is contradictory. Call either `pack()` or `setSize()` (preferrably `pack()`).

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane` are not meant to be embedded in a `JFrame` but are rather meant to be displayed in a dialog.

Now, I see 3 ways to achieve what you want:

1. Scan recursively the `JOptionPane` component hierarchy to find `JButton` and add `ActionListener`. The drawback of this solution is that you have to identify somehow which button is which (components order may change according to different L&F).
2. Override `JOptionPane.setValue(Object object)` which is invoked when a button is clicked.
3. **UPDATE** Simply add a `PropertyChangeListener` which listens for changes on the `JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY`. You will get notified everytime a button is hit.

Option 3 seems the most appropriate and with the minimum amount of code.

Here is a snippet of this second solution. Feel free to enhance the anonymous class into an inner class or even in its own file so that you can have better methods to access this.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestOptionPane {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Some message", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {
            @Override
            public void setValue(Object newValue) {
                super.setValue(newValue);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "You have hit " + newValue);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new JLabel("Some panel in the middle") {
            @Override
            public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 500);
            };
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestOptionPane().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are intended ways to use constructors of `JOptionPane` which are public then?

Comment: @SuzanCioc If you wish to somehow do something additional on them. Never had to do that, but why not. Anyway, I found a better solution. I will update my answer with it

Comment: @SuzanCioc I have updated my answer with a 3rd much better solution and which actually provides one reason to be able to access the public Constructors of `JOptionPane`

Answer (score 0):

You can catch an event by using `pane.showConfirmDialog()`. It will return, depending on the situation, either `JOptionPane.YES` or `JOptionPane.CANCEL`.
Despite that, I think you need to create a conventional `JPanel`, because `JOptionPane` is for pop-up dialogs, not to embed on a `JFrame`.
You see, even if you CAN, it doesn't mean you SHOULD do something.

Answer (score 0):

This is want you want.

```
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Stackoverflow", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    JPanel buttonArea = (JPanel) pane.getComponents()[1];

    JButton b1 = (JButton)buttonArea.getComponent(0);
    JButton b2 = (JButton)buttonArea.getComponent(1);

    b1.removeActionListener(b1.getActionListeners()[0]);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Stackoverflow");
        }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```